# Macのロック画面をソフトウェアから解除したい。

Tags: swift, macos

いつもお世話になっております。

この度、Macのソフトウェア開発をしているのですが、そのソフトウェアからMacIDというソフトのようにロック画面を解除したいのです。
調べてみたのですが、どうやら
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1
が参考になるそうですが、あまり理解しきれず困っています。

どなたかご存じないでしょうか？

ちなみにSwiftで開発をしています。
よろしくお願いします。